# How can I efficiently display large volumes of text using SwiftUI?

Tags: macos, swiftui

See this sample app: https://github.com/conorgriffin/TextInScrollviewPerformance

When loading the `sample.txt` from the repository, the CPU goes to 100% and the app completely hangs when using this view code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var document: TextInScrollviewPerformanceDocument

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text(document.text)
        }
    }
}
```

However, there's no such issue when using this code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var document: TextInScrollviewPerformanceDocument

    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $document.text)
    }
}
```

Presumably because `TexEditor` is more efficient at handling lots of text.

I also used `Text` without the `ScrollView` as follows which does not cause the CPU spike, but since I need to be able to scroll the full output it's not what I need and the fact that most of the text gets truncated probably explains the reason it doesn’t cause the app to hang.

```
Text(document.text)
```

So the problem seems to be exclusively caused by the `Text` inside the `ScrollView` and in particular, it's noticeable when the file is over a certain size.

How can I efficiently present a read-only view of a large volume of text using SwiftUI where I can also style the text using `AttributedString`?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you are looking for. `Text` without a `ScrollView` truncates most of the text, so of course it is faster than `Text` inside a `ScrollView`. `TextEditor` on the other hand is implemented very differently under the hood.

Comment: I’m trying to understand, I suppose if I’m doing something silly. The reason being that I would not have thought a 1.5 MB text file being loaded into a text element in a scrollview would hang the app indefinitely and cause the CPU to go to 100% for minutes.

Comment: No you are not doing something silly. SwiftUI `Text` just isn't very efficient in this regard. `Text` just isn't lazy like `TextEditor`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Maybe I should refine my question to ask how to efficiently display a large volume of text using SwiftUI

Comment: Yeah, I think that is what you should have asked in the first place. ["Why" questions are usually not good questions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/5133585)

Comment: In that case, the answer would be "use a `constant` binding with `TextEditor`" or, "make your own `NSViewRepresentable`".

Comment: Question reworded accordingly